# Query to Move data from one table column to other table

Tags: sql, sybase

Consider Table1 with following data

```
CustomerId  Division    email
C1  D1  abc@xyz.com
C1  D2  abc@xyz.com

C2  D1  mnc@xyz.com
C2  D2  mnc@xyz.com
```

I need to write sql to move email column data to the below Table2
The result should be as follows 
Consider Table2 with following data ( CustomerId is not primary key)

```
CustomerId  email   Type
C1  abc@xyz.com 
C2  mnc@xyz.com
```

Please can anyone give sql for this and the values in Table2 should always be unique customerId?

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?) and version? what does Table2 look like **before** you move the data ... is Table2 empty? do you know, for a fact, that multiple entries in Table1 for a given CustomerId will have the same email address?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select distinct customerid, email, null as type
from table1;
```

Comment: I get an ISQL warning  "The result returned is non-deterministic"

Comment: @ShobhaM . . . If that is a concern for you, add an `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
INSERT INTO Table2(CustomerId, email)
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId, email FROM Table1;
```

In this, we are fetching the only distinct record not duplicate records.

Thanks.

Comment: I  get an ISQL warning "The result returned is non-deterministic"

Comment: Okay, you only getting warning ?